# How can I check string equals certain value and set to true?

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a *one liner* that checks a string value for a certain value ans set `x` to `true` or `false`..So like

```
x = if s="boat"
```

**`if s= "boat, x will be true`**

Comment: `var x = s === 'boat';`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the value of 's' is a string.

Try the code below:

```
var x = s === 'boat';
```

Answer (score 1):

> Use [**`Identity / strict equality (===)`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity_strict_equality_())

*The identity operator returns `true` if the operands are equal(**with no type conversion**) and `false` otherwise.*

```js
var s = 'boat';
var x = s == 'boat';
console.log(x);
```